# Cabecera Authorization HTTP

Tags: http, autenticación

Estoy usando Digest Authentication para verificar si un usuario conoce la ID y PW del servidor. Una vez que el cliente ha ingresado al servidor porque conoce las credenciales (el servidor ha emparejado su respuesta de hash con la respuesta de hash del cliente), todas sus solicitudes tienen el encabezado Authorization. ¿Esto es normal? ¿El encabezado de autorización no se envía solo una vez?

Una vez que el cliente ha aprobado el Digest Challenge, todas sus solicitudes son como las siguientes (todas las solicitudes tienen el encabezado Authorization):

```
GET /XMLAliasRegDev HTTP/1.1
***Here's the Host***
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://***Here's the Host***/webpage/html/registry.htm
Authorization: Digest username="xxx", realm="xxx", nonce="b463d286b77fba6535adc1902e43377a", uri="/XMLAliasRegDev", response="4bedc10d3fd7f3fb90ab518ffead238b", opaque="eb2cdfdb6ebd0e78c0737bc4d58d0d3c"
Connection: keep-alive


GET /webpage/scripts/regjs.js HTTP/1.1
***Here's the Host***
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://***Here's the Host***/webpage/html/registry.htm
Authorization: Digest username="xxx", realm="xxx", nonce="b463d286b77fba6535adc1902e43377a", uri="/webpage/scripts/regjs.js", response="95cd7035c6abf7666fbdb0068aa69b9a", opaque="eb2cdfdb6ebd0e78c0737bc4d58d0d3c"
Connection: keep-alive
```

Si el servidor ha hecho matching de las respuestas, estas han coincidido, y el servidor envía los recursos al cliente porque el cliente ha introducido las credenciales correctas, ¿por qué el cliente envía el encabezado de autorización en cada petición? Es la manera de funcionar del Digest Authentication?

Muchas gracias!

PD: estoy usando Arduino como servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es asi como funciona, debido a que HTTP es un protocolo sin estado una vez autorizado hay que enviar credenciales en cada petición. simplificando bastante el [ejemplo del rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.5), el ida y vuelta es mas o menos asi :

al primer request del cliente el servidor le dice 401 (eh! necesito identificación) le da un token compuesto de nonce (valor de un sólo uso) un opaque (indicador de estado de sesión) y un realm (ámbito) de autenticación. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.1

`Client request (no authentication)`

```
GET /dir/index.html HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
```

`Server response`

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Server: HTTPd/0.9
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2014 20:26:47 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="testrealm@host.com",
                        qop="auth,auth-int",
                        nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093",
                        opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>401 Unauthorized.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

el cliente pide clave al usuario toma el realm y el nonce/opaque y genera un token de auth (response) que envía junto a la petición original (incluye un numero de orden nc y un nonce de cliente cnonce). https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.2

`Client request (username "Mufasa", password "Circle Of Life")`

```
GET /dir/index.html HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
Authorization: Digest username="Mufasa",
                     realm="testrealm@host.com",
                     nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093",
                     uri="/dir/index.html",
                     qop=auth,
                     nc=00000001,
                     cnonce="0a4f113b",
                     response="6629fae49393a05397450978507c4ef1",
                     opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"
```

el servidor recibe el token (nonce/response/opaque), nonce del cliente (cnonce), y calcula en base a esto si el ciente puede acceder al recurso. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.3

`Server response`

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: HTTPd/0.9
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2005 20:27:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 7984
```

si el cliente recibe un ok (200 OK) seguirá calculando en base al nonce/realm del primer 401 y enviando los cnonce y response calculados para evitar otro 401.

el servidor en cualquier momento puede invalidar esas credenciales y presentar otro 401 (necesita autorización) con otro nonce/opaque, indicar un 400 (bad request) y así.

La explicación en inglés del ejemplo:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Example_with_explanation